# Using Atlas Search with Mongoid on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to get full text search with Atlas to work in my Rails app. I have set up the index following [this tutorial in their docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/create-index/). When I test the query in a vacuum it seems to work as expected, I'm able to query my database and get the results I would expect, but it seems like the documentation around how to do this in Mongoid is lacking. I have found [this documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/current/reference/text-search/) for running text search in Mongoid, but it explicitly calls out that it isn't Atlas Search.

Has anybody successfully implemented an Atlas Search index/query using Mongoid (or otherwise in a Rails app) and, if so, could you please point me towards the relevant docs.

Answer (score 0):

Alright - after some experimentation with this I have found that the following code will work with the current version of mongoid:

```
TableName.collection.aggregate([{
    '$search' => {
        'index' => 'index_name',
        'text' => {
            'query' => 'some string to search',
            'path' => {
                'wildcard' => '*'
            }
        }
    }
}])
```